# A Diophantine Equation Revisited

Tags: diophantine-equations

This question relates to the one I just asked several hours ago:
Find $x+y$ if $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x^2+y^2 = 2019^2$. There is a short cut to this equation but I haven’t found it yet. I tried estimate $x+y$ but it has lots of possible outcomes. Any one sees the trick here? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $2019=3\cdot 673$ and $0^2+3^2=3^2$,
$$
385^2+552^2=673^2
$$
by using the formulas [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_of_primitive_Pythagorean_triples).
Now we can use [two square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity) by Brahmagupta to solve $2019^2=x^2+y^2$.

Comment: Very nice answer. I wonder how you express the $673^2$ as the sum of the squares of $385$ and $552$.

Comment: I used the wikipedia link with the formula $(m^2-n^2,2mn,m^2+n^2)$ and $(m,n)=(23,12)$. Then $m^2-n^2=(m+n)(m-n)=35\cdot 11=385$ and so on.